# SSRS ReportViewer slow to render report with HTML5 renderer

Tags: javascript, html, reporting-services, reportviewer, ssrs-2008-r2

ReportViewer version: 14

I have a reporting view that displays a list of all my team's reports grouped like so:

```
ReportGroup1
    Report1
    Report2
    Report3

ReportGroup2
    Report4
    Report5
    Report6
...
```

When I run this report in the browser (Chrome 60) it is very slow, taking upwards of 5 minutes to run. There are nearly 1000 rows returned in this report including a couple icons next to each report's name and links to each report in a new window. Despite the browser slowness, the SQL query is instantaneous and the report also renders quickly using the Preview function in Visual Studio.

I monitored the performance with Developer Tools and it appears the new HTML5 additions are causing a bottleneck, specifically the `Resize100HeightElements()` and `Resize100WidthElements()` functions in `Html5Renderer.js`. If my understanding is correct, it is dynamically resizing each of these rows based on the height of their parent, which takes a considerable amount of time with ~1000 objects.

A workaround is to set the `InteractiveSize` to a small size (e.g. `8.5 in`) which limits the number of rows returned on a given page (we had it set to `0`, which prints all results on one page). We would prefer not to break this out into pages, though.

Does anyone know of an alternative way to speed up long pages or a way to increase performance of the HTML5 renderer? An upgrade to SSRS 2016 is in the near future, for what that's worth. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Performance is significantly improved when the report does not contain any images, even though the image size property in the report is set to Clip and not Fit Proportional. How can we keep our images without being bogged down by the HTML5 renderer?

Comment: Nice research into the issue.  Can you see what overhead the icons are adding to everything? A couple thousand icons on a single page will seriously degrade load times as well from my experience.  Are the icons optimized and scaled well already?

Comment: The icons are small and appear to be scaled well, and there are < 10 icons being returned in the request. According to the summary, the two aforementioned function calls took up 99.4% of the execution time but it was hard to determine if that was caused by scaling icons. I tried deploying the report with no icons and it was *way* faster. I ran the DevTools performance monitor again and it confirms that performance has significantly improved. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Icons in SSRS have always been a troublesome area in my experience.  Scaling rarely goes well in terms of quality or performance.

Comment: I can understand that, but we also had these icons when we used an older version of the report viewer (before the HTML5 code was introduced) and it was much faster with the old version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that is sufficient for our needs.

Setting image size to **Original Size** in the **Image Properties** is the only option I found won't cause a significant slowdown when rendering large pages. I had to do this for all *visible* images; the image size makes no difference on hidden images. When I reevaluated the performance using Chrome Developer Tools, I could see that both the render time and script execution time decreased significantly. The report now runs in < 5 seconds where it was closer to 5 minutes before.

I suspect the image size was previously set to Clip because SSRS does not offer any sort of alignment options for images in a cell like they do for text in a textbox, according to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chrishays/2004/10/27/centered-images/) page. I was able to work around this by inserting a rectangle into each cell containing images, then moving each image to sit inside the rectangle in its cell. I then adjusted the padding properties individually until each image was centered.